# A Question about Euler’s Equations when Auxiliary Conditions are Imposed

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

In the Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems book, by Stephen T. Thornton and Jerry B. Marion, page 220, the author derived Equation (6.67) from Equation (6.66) which is the following:

Equation (6.67):
$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} − \ \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^′}\right)\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)^{−1} = \ 
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} − \ \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z^′}
\right)
\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}
\right)^{−1}$$

Because $y$ and $z$ are both functions of $x$, the two sides of Equation (6.67) may be set equal to a function of $x$ which we write as $\lambda(x)$:

Equations (6.68):
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} − \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^′} + \lambda(x)\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} − \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z^′} + \lambda(x)\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} = 0$$

where $\lambda(x)$ is the Lagrange undetermined multiplier.

How did the author deduce Equations (6.68) from Equation (6.67)?

Actually, I am a physicist and not a mathematician. I am not an expert in Calculus of Variations. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: He just took the equality of LHS of 6.67 with $- \lambda(x)$ and rearranged terms. The same with the RHS.